# How to go to next and previous and loop them

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a situation where i need to go to `next` and `previous` **div content**

**for example:**

if user clicks `CTRL + n` or `next`  then it should go to **(1st time run)**

1. first div content (if cliked CTRL + n)
2. second div content (if cliked CTRL + n)
3. third div content

   so on .....

for previous this pattern will continue

**below is my whole code:**

```js
$(function(){

    // CTRL + n   ===> Next
    
    //CTRL + p    ===> Previous
    
    var index = 0;
    $('#next').on('click',function(){
        
    });
    
    $('#previous').on('click',function(){
        
    });
    
   // window.location = '#third'   should change dynamically

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#first">
  first
</a>

<a href="#second">
   second
</a>

<a href="#third">
   third
</a>

<a href="#fourth">
   fourth
</a>

<div id="first">
   <hr>
   First
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae provident quibusdam maiores laudantium rem quas doloremque expedita tempora omnis, accusantium vel, consectetur eos ratione modi alias obcaecati numquam sapiente temporibus.
   
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis quam ipsam voluptates sit minus minima quas quasi itaque error natus, exercitationem, praesentium, laudantium voluptas ut quidem dolore? Rem, id quasi.
</div>

<div id="second">
   <hr>
   Second
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus illo harum, numquam optio iure quae ducimus ipsam velit corporis quidem omnis fugiat expedita autem vitae magni molestiae doloribus, ullam mollitia.
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, asperiores eum rem, nostrum provident qui sunt ut neque, consequatur quaerat repellendus error? Aliquam deleniti cum et error in, at voluptate.
</div>

<div id="third">
   <hr>
   Third 
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, officia? Id voluptatem voluptas similique, reprehenderit odit ab! Laboriosam deserunt illo est obcaecati quaerat, consequuntur, maxime quia quisquam corrupti recusandae, voluptas.
   
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit repellendus laborum molestiae asperiores necessitatibus repellat eveniet, obcaecati blanditiis numquam aut soluta veritatis unde, quis, dicta illo dolorem, consectetur temporibus molestias!
</div>

<div id="fourth">
   <hr>
   Fourth
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut ea tempore corrupti, hic vitae repudiandae quod cumque fugiat iste qui accusantium ipsam amet inventore, dignissimos magnam? Ipsam error eaque inventore!
   
   
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum ipsa itaque eius accusantium. Necessitatibus fugiat dolorum rerum, quam praesentium, aliquam sapiente molestias maiores molestiae. Facilis officia cupiditate quae nisi animi.
</div>

<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>  |
<a href="#" id="previous">Previous</a>
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jLqt2d1g/9/

Comment: Well, you almost there. You have all you need. In next / prev change the `index` and then map from `index` to the `id`s and put it in a variable, `selectedSection` for example. (Or just change their `id`s to something like `#section1`, `#section2` etc.) and then call `location.href = selectedSection`

Answer (score 1):

See the JS fiddle link [JSFiddle(next and previous function)](https://jsfiddle.net/jLqt2d1g/45/)

```
$(function(){

// CTRL + n   ===> Next

//CTRL + p    ===> Previous
var id_arr=["first","second","third","fourth"];

var index = 0;
$('#next').on('click',function(){
        index++;
    var div_id = id_arr[index];
    if(index>5){
        alert('No More div in this Page');
    }else{
        alert(div_id);

      //based on div_id show the div in page
    }
});

$('#previous').on('click',function(){
    index--;
    var div_id = id_arr[index];
    if(index<0){
        alert('No More div in this Page');
    }else{
        alert(div_id);

      //based on div_id show the div in page
    }
});
```

// window.location = '#third'   should change dynamically

});

i am updated code in the JSfiddle refer that code

In that code in next and previous function you will get the div_id's based on the div'id show div in page